# How do you get the list outside of the loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script to pull the data from the database.

I would like to get some help with the variable `channel` outside of the `for index in range` loop.

When I try this:

```
    for row in cur:
        channels = row[0].encode('ascii')
        channelList.append(channels)

    for index in range(0, CHANNELS_PER_PAGE):
        channel = channelList[index]

        print channel
        #get the programs list
        cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM 
programs WHERE channel=?', [channel])
        programs = cur.fetchall()
        start_pos = 368    # indent for first program
        for row in programs:
            title = row[1].encode('ascii')
```

If I use the code on above to print channel in `for index in range` loop, i will get this:

```
23:32:03 T:1164  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
23:32:03 T:1164  NOTICE: 102 CBS
23:32:03 T:1164  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
23:32:03 T:1164  NOTICE: 105 ESPN USA
23:32:03 T:1164  NOTICE: 106 Fox News
23:32:03 T:1164  NOTICE: 107 Animal Planet
23:32:03 T:1164  NOTICE: 108 USA Network
```

So when I try this:

```
    for row in cur:
        channels = row[0].encode('ascii')
        channelList.append(channels)

    for index in range(0, CHANNELS_PER_PAGE):
        channel = channelList[index]

    print channel
    #get the programs list
    cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs 
WHERE channel=?', [channel])
    programs = cur.fetchall()
    start_pos = 368    # indent for first program
    for row in programs:
        title = row[1].encode('ascii')
```

If I use `print channel` outside of the loop, i will get this:

```
23:30:09 T:5828  NOTICE: 108 USA Network
```

I want to put the loop `for row in programs:` outside of the `for index in range` loop with the variable `channel` to preventing my code firing.

How do you use to get the list of channels to allow me to print for each channel outside of the `for index in range` loop?

Answer (score 0):

In the first program, for each channel in your channel list, you print its name and fetch the programs from the database. However, in the second program, you removed the indentation. This causes your program to print and fetch only the last channel from the channel list.

This, using the logic of your program, you should not remove the `for row in programs` from the outer `from index in range`, although you could use some [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and get it done.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Matheus. Are there any other way if I can fetch the channels from the database with the range 0 to 7 by using a different way if that is possible?

Comment: There may exist a few options to refactor your code, however it strongly depends on what your are going to use it for. What is your objective by changing it the way it is right now?